# 3d views missing when translating .rvt to .svf

Tags: autodesk-forge, autodesk-model-derivative

Today I attempted to translate a `.rvt` file to `.svf`. I wanted to only translate the 3d views. The output of the job, however, was only 2d views instead of the expected 3d views. I had ran this process on a similar file just a few minutes before with the same parameters and it worked as expected.

As I understand it, if I specify `"type":"svf"` and `"views":["3d"]` then the job should only return 3d derivatives, which was not the case. Am I missing something here?

Model Derivative Post Body

```
{
  "input": {
    "urn": "dXJuOmFk...sucnZ0"
  },
  "output": {
    "formats": [
      {
        "type": "svf",
        "views": [
          "3d"
        ]
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

Model Derivative Response `200 OK`

```
{
  "result": "success",
  "urn": "dXJuOmFk...sucnZ0",
  "acceptedJobs": {
    "output": {
      "formats": [
        {
          "type": "svf",
          "views": [
            "3d"
          ]
        }
      ]
    }
  }
}
```

Model Derivative Manifest Result

```
{
  "type": "manifest",
  "hasThumbnail": "true",
  "status": "success",
  "progress": "complete",
  "region": "US",
  "urn": "dXJuOmFk...sucnZ0",
  "version": "1.0",
  "derivatives": [
    {
      "name": "00000_AnyCity_P12_LC_EQK.rvt",
      "hasThumbnail": "true",
      "status": "success",
      "progress": "complete",
      "outputType": "svf",
      "children": [
        {
      "guid": "6fac95cb-af5d-3e4f-b943-8a7f55847ff1",
      "type": "resource",
      "role": "Autodesk.CloudPlatform.PropertyDatabase",
      "urn": "urn:adsk.viewing:fs.file:dXJuOmFk...sucnZ0/output/Resource/model.sdb",
      "mime": "application/autodesk-db",
      "status": "success"
        },
        {
          "guid": "9a5308f5-16b3-4497-ba36-c22d6f1381bf-00507cc3",
          "type": "geometry",
          "role": "2d",
          "name": "K-601L - ELECTRICAL ROUGH-IN ELEVATIONS",
          "viewableID": "9a5308f5-16b3-4497-ba36-c22d6f1381bf-00507cc3",
          "phaseNames": "New Construction",
          "ViewSets": "Set 1 LRG",
          "status": "success",
          "progress": "complete",
          "properties": {
            "Print Setting": {
              "Layout": "Landscape",
              "Paper size": "ISO A4, 210 x 297 mm"
            }
          },
          "hasThumbnail": "true",
          "children": [
            ...
          ]
        },
        ...
        {
          "guid": "9a5308f5-16b3-4497-ba36-c22d6f1381bf-00507cf9",
          "type": "geometry",
          "role": "2d",
          "name": "K-212L - ENLARGED EQUIPMENT FLOOR PLAN",
          "viewableID": "9a5308f5-16b3-4497-ba36-c22d6f1381bf-00507cf9",
          "phaseNames": "New Construction",
          "ViewSets": "Set 1 LRG",
          "status": "success",
          "progress": "complete",
          "properties": {
            "Print Setting": {
              "Layout": "Landscape",
              "Paper size": "ISO A4, 210 x 297 mm"
            }
          },
          "hasThumbnail": "true",
          "children": [
            ...
          ]
        }
      ]
    },
    {
      "status": "success",
      "progress": "complete",
      "outputType": "thumbnail",
      "children": [
        ...
      ]
    }
  ]
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to explicitly specify which 3D views to include in the translation.

This is done by selecting them in the C4R UI, as described in the following blog posts:

- [Selecting RVT 3D Views for Forge Translation](https://thebuildingcoder.typepad.com/blog/2016/07/selecting-views-for-forge-translation.html)
- [Roomedit3d Update for Connecting Desktop and Forge](http://thebuildingcoder.typepad.com/blog/2016/09/roomedit3d-update-for-connecting-desktop-and-forge.html)
- [NuGet Package Update, Rooms and Views in Forge](http://thebuildingcoder.typepad.com/blog/2017/09/revit-20181-nuget-packages-rooms-and-views-in-forge.html)

[image]

Comment: Based on the first blog post, shouldn't the Model Derivative API still load at least the standard `{3D}` 3D view? And does the Model Derivative API default to 2D views if no 3D views are found?

Comment: I would have expected that too, but who knows? I assume the (i) you cannot trust anything whatsoever (ii) you therefore have to test it yourself and (iii) you have to retest daily, so include this in your daily unit test.